# SPARK Reading CSV from FTP: Input path does not exist

Tags: csv, apache-spark, ftp, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do something that is supposed to be quite straightforward, but can't manage to do it.

I have a .csv file in a FTP server from a customer. The path is something as such:

`ftp://[user]:[passwd]@[IP-ADDRESS]/file.csv`

By copy and pasting the address, I can easily access the file on my browser (or any other program). But I can't access it on pyspark.

Here is what I'm trying to do, using databricks spark-csv (https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

```
file_path = ftp://[user]:[passwd]@[IP-ADDRESS]/file.csv
reader = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
         .options(header=False, charset='cp860', inferschema='true', delim=";")
         .load(file_path)
```

and I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: ftp://[user]:[passwd]@[IP-ADDRESS]/file.csv
```

Trying to read file as text file:

```
df = sqlContext.read.text("ftp://[user]:[passwd]@[IP-ADDRESS]/SALES_37_TIRADENTES_2016-09-01.csv", )
df.collect()
```

error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o147.collectToPython.
: java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job
```

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with FTP access, but I'm not sure.

---

### EDIT

I ended up downloading the file using the Python's `ftplib` and loading the file into the RDD. Probably a suboptimal approach, if the size of your data is way too big, but it works.

Comment: Are you able to download sample files from any sites that doesn't require userid/password?

Comment: No luck reading from `ftp.debian.org/debian/README`

Answer (score 3):

You can use file from FTP using **SparkFiles**
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html

**addFile(path)**

Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node. The path passed can be either a local file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI.

To access the file in Spark jobs, use L{SparkFiles.get(fileName)} with the filename to find its download location.

```
>>> from pyspark import SparkFiles
>>> path = os.path.join(tempdir, "test.txt")
>>> with open(path, "w") as testFile:
...    _ = testFile.write("100")
>>> sc.addFile(path)
>>> def func(iterator):
...    with open(SparkFiles.get("test.txt")) as testFile:
...        fileVal = int(testFile.readline())
...        return [x * fileVal for x in iterator]
>>> sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4]).mapPartitions(func).collect()
[100, 200, 300, 400]
```

The following was tested (pyspark - 1.5.2) to be working:

```
from pyspark import SparkFiles

file_path = "ftp://ftp:ftp@ftp.ed.ac.uk/pub/Unix/Win2000_PlainPassword.reg"
sc.addFile(file_path)

filename = SparkFiles.get(file_path.split('/')[-1])

rdd = sc.textFile("file://"+filename)
rdd.take(10)
rdd.collect()
```

Comment: Almost there. `sc.addFile` does add the file to a `tmp` dir. But I still can't open it, neither using the file_name nor the return value from `SparkFiles.get(file_name)`, that correctly returns the local file path.

Comment: @ArthurCamara please try the suggestion in my update

Comment: I was already doing that. `df.collect()` fails with the same error. The thing is: when open the file and reading the line, it works. Indicating that the file is actually present.

Also, worth noting, I'm running Spark 1.6.2, not 2.0 yet (We relies on IBM's Bluemix)

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry, the error now says `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/spark-160-ego-master/work/spark-69648973-8776-4bc4-91e9-61605c7f4d3d/userFiles-d790dfaa-b665-4afa-a08c-057d61831b8d/file.csv does not exist`

Comment: Still can't find the file on 1.6.0.  I'm thinking that this is an issue with IBM's Bluemix servers.

Comment: Even I m facing the same problem any help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that might help (scala version, tested with spark 1.6.3)

First get the file with the **wholeTextFiles** method from the Spark Context

```
val dataSource = "ftp://[user]:[passwd]@[IP-ADDRESS]"

val fileRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles(dataSource).values
```

and then instantiate a CsvParser with your options

```
val csvParser: CsvParser = new CsvParser().withUseHeader(true).withInferSchema(true).withDelimiter(';').withCharset("cp860")
```

*(if you don't want to use the header, don't forget to remove the first line)*

and finally

```
val df = csvParser.csvRdd(sq, fileRDD)
df.collect()
```

Hope this helps !